# Problems rendering GET JSON response from API in a flatlist

Tags: react-native

I need to create an app that interacts with an API that stores information about customers.

I have created a `getCustDetail` function which will request the info about acustomer using a `GET` method.

This is what the server should send when a request is sent to the API:

```
{
    "cust_id": 1,
    "given_name": "John",
    "family_name": "Smith",
    "email": "smith99@hotmail.com",
    "recent_purchases": [
        {
            "item_id": 1,
            "price": 20,
            "item_descr": "Small apple”
        },
        {
            "item_id ": 2,
            " price ": 15,
            "item_descr": "Sponge Cake”
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

This is my get `GET` function that gets the response and stores it in :

```
userDetails: [] state
```

I tried converting the response JSON string to an array so it could be displayed in my flatlists using the `object.values` function:

```
'userDetail: Object.values(resJson),'
```

```
getCustDetails () {
      return fetch(‘API URL HERE’,  
         {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
         })
         .then((res) => res.json())
         .then((resJson) => {
            this.setState({
               userDetail: Object.values(resJson),
            });
            console.log("The server response is :" + this.state.userDetail)
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
         });
   }
```

The console log message from the getuserdetail function :

```
"The server response is : 1,John,Smith,smith99@hotmail.com,[object Object],[object Object]"
```

My flatlist set up to get the customer details and display them in the app:

```
       <FlatList
           data={this.state.myDetails}
           keyExtractor={({ user_id }) => user_id}
           renderItem={({ item }) => <View style={styles.list}>
              <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item.cust_id }</Text>
              <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item.given_name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item.family_name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item.email}</Text>
           </View>}
        />
```

When I try get the customer info on my app, blank flatlist texts  appear with no data in them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
renderItem={({ item }) => <View style={styles.list}>
          <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item[0] }</Text>
          <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item[1]}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item[2]}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item[3]}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `extraData` props to Flatlist. As described in document :

> By passing extraData={selected} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

So make your Flatlist like this :

```js
<FlatList
  data={this.state.myDetails}
  extraData={this.state}
  keyExtractor={({ user_id }) => user_id}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.list}>
      <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item.cust_id }</Text>
      <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item.given_name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item.family_name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.ListText}>{item.email}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

Also note that I have made changes on `renderItem`. Curly braces are recommending to use.